# Cocos2d-x:Draw number of life in the game by an image

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to draw number of life in my game by number of image
I'm using sprite but it can not be add more than 1.
What object should i need to do that, i searched on google it tell me CCSpriteFrame, but i do not know how to use it, i'm newbie.
Please help me and give me a sample.
Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Yo can not add same sprite object more than one. However you can create a new object of `CCSprite` with same image and add it to parent. Once you have created an object of `CCSprite` then image is cached by `SharedTextureCache` and it wont load again and again if you create `CCSprite` object using same image until you haven't manually cleared `SharedTextureCache`.

Comment: But if i want to add 5 sprites, it take many lines of code, is there any other way to do ?+

Comment: Store images names in a array and then you can use loop to add Sprites.